# How to parse only one array of JSON file in BB 10 using CPP

Tags: c++, json, blackberry-10

I have the  below Json file called `details.json`

```
{
  "text": [
    {
     "id":"123",
      "name":"John",
      "age":"20"

    },
    {
      "id":"234",
      "name":"David",
      "age":"21"

    },
    {
      "id":"345",
      "name":"July",
      "age":"22"

    }

  ]
}
```

I know little bit of parsing.I want to parse this Json file using CPP in BB10. Based on my requirement when clicked on a button only the  FIRST ARRAY DETAILS will be displayed like only "123, John ,20". No need do display other array values. But I am getting the whole Json file values.

Comment: What is your question exactly? What code have you written so far and what problem do you have with it?

Comment: share your code. it would be more helpful to solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Download JSON library from:

https://bitbucket.org/tunnuz/json

Use `Value` class to wrap this string, and use one of `get` methods.

**Please read and follow the documentation.** I won't be able to answer more.